# Using php curl proxy for surfing a website

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I want to set up a webpage to use proxy automatically. Here is my script:

```
<?

$url = 'http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/jrnlallbooks/a/fulltext';
$proxy = '200.93.148.72:3128';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);


echo $curl_scraped_page;

?>
```

I can open the webpage and the header shows:

HTTP/1.0 200 OK Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2012 18:46:41 GMT Last-Modified: Fri, 23 Nov 2012 18:46:41 GMT Set-Cookie: MIAMISESSION=86e5ecb0-359b-11e2-b116-00000aab0f6c:3531149201; path=/; domain=.sciencedirect.com; Set-Cookie: USER_STATE_COOKIE=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 23:59:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.sciencedirect.com; Set-Cookie: SD_REMOTEACCESS=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 23:59:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.sciencedirect.com; Set-Cookie: MIAMIAUTH=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; path=/; domain=.sciencedirect.com; Set-Cookie: TARGET_URL=fcf74dd786744d87fbaaaf8652a764ab4a79b0d3ed681139e9106923760631052596d348948479933da48b3723069bbf09065290c950dc02c1f0d1436659ad5a; path=/; domain=.sciencedirect.com; Set-Cookie: MIAMIAUTH=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; path=/; domain=.sciencedirect.com; Content-Type: text/html Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT X-RE-Ref: 0 19194695 Server: www.sciencedirect.com P3P: CP="IDC DSP LAW ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVA IVD CON HIS TEL OUR DEL SAM OTR IND OTC" Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent X-Cache: MISS from alejandria.ufps.edu.co X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from alejandria.ufps.edu.co:3128 Via: 1.0 alejandria.ufps.edu.co (squid/3.0.STABLE15) Proxy-Connection: close

However, the proxy only works on this page. When I click other links on this page, no proxy is loaded. Please help me to solve this. How to improve my script? I want a whole website (all links) to use the proxy. How to set up?

Comment: Instead of setting up a PHP proxy have you considered letting you webserver handle the proxying?

Comment: It's easy to set up the proxy in the explorer. But I want a script inside the webpage to use proxy. Then others can also visit the link by the proxy I set up

Answer (score 1):

It seems that You need to use regular expressions to modify any links within the HTML code (for example `<a href="...">`) to point to Your script. Then You have to set up an argument to cURL, so You'll get proper page, so it'll look something like `http://YourSite.com/proxy.php?site=http://example.com/smth/foo.php`

Comment: I use a free webhost which support curl. My testing url is: http://webworms.webgratis.cat/proxy.php. How to add a href= to all links? Hope your detailed teaching. Thank you very much!